# Is it possible to start an application by hotkey, without 3rd party software? If so, how?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hotkeys

Is there a way to setup some key combination on Windows 7 to call a specific `.exe` file without installing any sort of third party application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you have to do is create a shortcut to it (on the desktop, or in the Start menu*). Then right-click it, select Properties, click in the "Shortcut key" field under the Shortcut tab, and press your desired key combination. Click OK and then it should work.

*Note that this method only works if the shortcut is in certain places. See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134552) for more information.

Comment: Try and keep your "global key shortcuts" on the desktop , or in the start menu itself. I think also desktop icons do not work if desktop icons are completly hidden.  If you have problems with conficts while making them, re-boot.

Comment: In Windows, the shortcut key typically only works if the shortcut is on the Desktop or in the Start menu, see [Shortcut key for shortcut does not work](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134552). That KB article doesn't mention Windows 7, but I don't know if it's left out on purpose or because the document is out of date.

Comment: It seems that, at least in Windows 7, this works only if you pin the shortcut to the Start Menu. If you place it on the Desktop, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to pin the app and then using WinKey +  to launch it - that is built in and does not require additional apps.

It does not use Ctrl shortcut however.